# Display HTML dynamically using Knockout MVC using ko.If with Nullable Datetime

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-mvc

I'm new to Knockout MVC and I'm trying to display a `<img />` if the selected date is a Saturday ou Sunday. I want it to be display as soon as I change the value (No form submit).

My try was using "using(ko.If( ... ))" :

**MODEL**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public bool Weekend
    {
        get
        {
            if (Date.HasValue)
            {
                return Date.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || Date.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model MyApp.TestModel
@{
     var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
```

...

```
@ko.Html.TextBox(x => x.Date, new { class="datefield" })
using(ko.If(x => x.Date.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || x.Date.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
{
    <img src="~/Images/warning-icon.png" width="22" height="22" title="Warning, it's the weekend." />
}
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datefield").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd M yy', changeYear: true });
});
</script>
@ko.Apply(Model)
```

I tried with this approach, but it says that it can't parse binding because of "Value()".
I managed to make it work with a CheckBox with a bool and a TextBox with a string condition... but can't with a datetime.

Hope I'm clear about my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Q.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave up trying to use Knockout MVC with DateTime (Works fine with String and Bool).

I used jQuery in order to display the block I wanted.
Just set an id on my img (warningWeekend) and modify the datepicker script

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$('#warningWeekend').hide('fast');
    $(".datefield").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd M yy',
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                    if (date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6) {
                        $('#warningWeekend').show('fast');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#warningWeekend').hide('fast');
                    }
        }
    });

</script>
```